# Sciplot c++ for scatter plots

Tags: c++, plot, data-visualization, diagram, scatter

Has anyone used the sciplot library in c++ for creating scatter plots?
https://sciplot.github.io/

I am fine with the examples for "normal" plots but I wonder if I am also able to create a scatter plot.
I do not find something in the documentation which mentions scatter plots.

An example code snippet would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vec x = { 1, 2, 3 };
Vec y = { 4, 5, 6 };

Plot plot;
  
plot.drawPoints(x, y).pointType(0);

plot.show();
```